# Catch NSNotification from another GCD queue

Tags: swift, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch, nsnotifications

I'm running the background process using this code:

```
func launchTor(hashedPassword hash : String) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
    // Do some stuff here
    let observer = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName("AppTerminates", object: nil, queue: nil) {
            notification -> Void in
            print("Terminating...")
            // Do smh here
        }
    }
    // Just some more stuff
}
```

Is there any way to specify the queue (GCD) that needs to catch the notification?

Comment: Looks like the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What is the initial issue/task?

Comment: @werediver It's more than just interesting question. You can do that for `NSQueue` by default and I wonder if the same is possible with `GCD`

Comment: Could you please show me the link to the `NSQueue` class reference? Can't find it. And it's not clear to me what do you want to achieve, because it seems to me that you want a run loop and not just async task (what is GCD for).

Comment: @werediver, you should look for `NSOperationQueue`. You can add observer to a specific queue, as it explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:)

Comment: So, `NSOperationQueue` is built over GCD and that is one of the provided extra (over GCD) featues. One way or another we can re-implement this functionality. Are you interested in such an implementation?

Comment: @werediver, thank you, post this as answer, please. No, I don't think re-implementing the existing functionality is worth trying, easier to use `NSOperationQueue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[- addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:) method is an extra feature provided by [NSOperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/) class which is *based on* Grand Central Dispatcher:

> Operation queues use the `libdispatch` library (also known as Grand Central Dispatch) to initiate the execution of their operations.

(from the beginning of the `NSOperationQueue` class reference)

This feature can be re-implemented if there are reasons for that (e.g. different behaviour or educational purposes), otherwise it may be worth switching to `NSOperationQueue` instead of bare GCD.